# JFET hidden wires detector

Tags: mosfet, jfet, field

I want make hidden wires (AC, 220V) detector (circuit is below), based on Soviet p-channel JFET transistor КП103, but JFET's now is very rare. Can i replace this JFET by any low-power MOSFET?[image: Детектор скрытой проводки]

My mistake, sorry. I attach КП303 circuit instead of КП103. But principle is the same.This is equivalent transistors with different channel type.

[image]

Comment: Can you find a data sheet for it?

Comment: http://www.5v.ru/ds/trnz/kp103.htm table with base characteristiks,(Russian language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll have a problem with this circuit. The original Soviet JFET may have been similar to the 2SK103 (but your schematic shows '303' and its also shown as an n-channel.

It's unclear to me whether the cutoff voltage needs to be higher or lower than the battery voltage, that and the rough value of Idss would provide sufficient information to select one of the many current JFETs. For example, J111 or BF862 (both n-channel).

Edit: With the revised schematic (p-channel) and datasheet, maybe a [PMBFJ177](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PMBFJ174_175_176_177_CNV.pdf) would do the trick. The original (M suffix) appears to have a cutoff higher than the battery voltage and an Idss (though I'm not sure of the Cyrillic) of some mA.

Answer (score 2):

> Can i replace this JFET by any low-power MOSFET?

No. MOSFETs function very differently. They are *usually* enhancement-mode devices, whereas JFETs are usually depletion-mode.

Nevertheless, you should be able to find JFET devices on the market. They're not as scarce as you may think.